# Corpus for anaphora resolution

Tags: corpora, anaphora

I need a test and train corpus for my project containing anaphora. It should atleast have 100 sentences. please help asap?

Comment: Should they be annotated, or just 100 (English?) sentences (that may or may not contain anaphora)?  If you need only 100 sentences, you can easily create a corpus by hand.

Comment: See also: opendata.stackexchange.com.

Comment: What question are you asking?

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this corpus at Linguistic data consortium: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T22

> The ARRAU (Anaphora Resolution and Underspecification) Corpus of Anaphoric Information was developed by the University of Essex and the University of Trento. It contains annotations of multi-genre English texts for anaphoric relations with information about agreement and explicit representation of multiple antecedents for ambiguous anaphoric expressions and discourse antecedents for expressions which refer to abstract entities such as events, actions and plans.
>
> The source texts in this release include task-oriented dialogues from the TRAINS-91 and TRAINS-93 corpora (the latter released through LDC, TRAINS Spoken Dialog Corpus LDC95S25), narratives from the English Pear Stories (a collection of narratives by subjects who watched a film and then recounted its contents), articles from the Wall Street Journal portions of the Penn Treebank (Treebank-2 LDC95T7) and the RST Discourse Treebank LDC2002T07, and the Vieira/Poesio Corpus which consists of training and test files from Treebank-2 and RST Discourse Treebank.
>
> LDC Catalog No.:  LDC2013T22

And also take a look at this: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume18/peral03a-html/node12.html